# Faster JanusGraph queries

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph

Previously my janusgraph was working fine with nearly 1000 elements. I made my graph 100k and now some queries are **very slow**. I'm using Cassandra as database backend and elastic search as index backend.

For example
`g.V().hasLabel('Person').union(count(), range(0, 15))` this takes 1.3 minutes. I just want to get 15 "Person". It should be fast.

`g.E().count()` takes 1.4 minutes. Why it is soo slow? I only have 200k nodes and 400k edges.

I also have some composite indexes for my "Person" node type. I have indexes for all the properties of "Person" node type

thanks for any advice

Comment: I would start by doing a `.profile()` on the queries to make sure that the query is using the index.

Comment: @KelvinLawrence I did run `.profile()`  78 seconds (99% of execution time) spend for JanusGraphStep([],[~label.eq(Person)]) 
So it seems not using indexes but can `count()` query use indexes? Do mixed indexes help this?

Answer (score 4):

Counting vertices with a specific label is a frequent use case that JanusGraph can only address by running a full table scan. So, for larger graphs counting becomes unbearably slow. Because the usecase is so frequent, an [issue](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/issues/926) was created for it.

If you use Janusgraph with an indexing backend for mixed indexes. it is possible to run a so-called direct index query in JanusGraph that can [return totals](https://docs.janusgraph.org/index-backend/direct-index-query/#query-totals) of index hits in a speedier way. This does not work on label filters, though, but on indexed properties.

Comment: 'direct index query' doesn't help for general cases. My queries consists of some conditions and then statements similar to `.union(count(), range(0, 15))` So I need to count varying things. Can indexes help it?